# Validation of textbox input in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, validation, user-input

How to validate a mobile number textbox and email textbox using regular expressions in C#?

I want to validate these first at the front end itself so that the database doesn't receive any invalid input or rather even checks for it.

I am using Windows Forms.

Comment: Is this an asp.net application, a windows forms application, or what?

Comment: What client technology are you using? Winforms, ASP.Net, WPF, ...?

Comment: @Paolo Tedesco : it's a WINFORM application

Comment: @Rewinder  : it's a WINFORM application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `System.Text.RegularExpression`

I'll give you an example for e-mail validation

then declare a regular expression like

```
Regex myRegularExpression = new 
                            Regex(" \b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b");
```

and say your e-mail textbox is `txtEmail`

then write,

```
   if(myRegularExpression.isMatch(txtEmail.Text))
   {
        //valid e-mail
   }
```

**Update**

Not an expert on regular expressions,

Here's the link to [Regular expression to validate e-mail](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

you can find more details about the regEx from the link provided.

Comment: can you explain me this --" \b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b"  ---------what is this allowing and what not? what is \b

Answer (score 3):

```
//for email validation    
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex rEMail = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]{2,28}[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$");

if (txt_email.Text.Length > 0)
{
    if (!rEMail.IsMatch(txt_email.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("E-Mail expected", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        txt_email.SelectAll();
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}

//for mobile validation    
Regex re = new Regex("^9[0-9]{9}");

if (re.IsMatch(txt_mobile.Text.Trim()) == false || txt_mobile.Text.Length > 10)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Indian Mobile Number !!");
    txt_mobile.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code will check whether an email address is valid:

```
string inputText = textBox1.Text;

if (Regex.IsMatch(inputText, 
                  @"^(?("")("".+?""@)|(([0-9a-zA-Z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-zA-Z])@))" + 
                  @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}))$"))
{
  MessageBox.Show("yes");
}
else
{
  MessageBox.Show("no");
}
```

(source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf.aspx)

For phone numbers, it's not so simple - the answer depends on where in the world you are, whether you want to allow international numbers, how mobiles are numbered (for example, in the USA, you can't tell from a phone number alone whether it's a mobile number or not).  Look up "Telephone numbering plan" on Wikipedia for more information.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET you can use a [RegularExpressionValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahwtc9e.aspx) control.

To determine the regular expression itself, you can experiment with a tool like [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm).

Be aware that validating emails with regular expressions is a hard task, if you want to allow all the possibly valid email formats; probably the best thing to do in that case would be to send an email to the entered address with a confirmation link, and when that link is clicked, you assume that the mail is valid.

Answer (score 1):

See *[Email Address Validation Using Regular Expression](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/EmailRegexValidator.aspx)* ([The Code Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Code_Project)) for email validation and see *[Best practice for parsing and validating mobile number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563377/best-practice-for-parsing-and-validating-mobile-number)* (Stack Overflow) for mobile number validation.

Answer (score 1):

I do the numeric validation this way as shown in the code below.

No need for checking char by char and user culture is respected!

```
namespace Your_App_Namespace
{
public static class Globals
{
    public static double safeval = 0; // variable to save former value!

    public static bool isPositiveNumeric(string strval, System.Globalization.NumberStyles NumberStyle)
    // checking if string strval contains positive number in USER CULTURE NUMBER FORMAT!
    {
        double result;
        boolean test;
        if (strval.Contains("-")) test = false;
        else test = Double.TryParse(strval, NumberStyle, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out result);
        // if (test == false) MessageBox.Show("Not positive number!");
        return test;
    }

    public static string numstr2string(string strval, string nofdec)
    // conversion from numeric string into string in USER CULTURE NUMBER FORMAT!
    // call example numstr2string("12.3456", "0.00") returns "12.34"
    {
        string retstr = "";
        if (Globals.isPositiveNumeric(strval, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number)) retstr = double.Parse(strval).ToString(nofdec);
        else retstr = Globals.safeval.ToString(nofdec);
        return retstr;
    }

    public static string number2string(double numval, string nofdec)
    // conversion from numeric value into string in USER CULTURE NUMBER FORMAT!
    // call example number2string(12.3456, "0.00") returns "12.34"
    {
        string retstr = "";
        if (Globals.isPositiveNumeric(numval.ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number)) retstr = numval.ToString(nofdec);
        else retstr = Globals.safeval.ToString(nofdec);
        return retstr;
    }
}

// Other Your_App_Namespace content

}

// This the way how to use those functions in any of your app pages

    // function to call when TextBox GotFocus

    private void textbox_clear(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txtbox = e.OriginalSource as TextBox;
        // save original value
        Globals.safeval = double.Parse(txtbox.Text);
        txtbox.Text = "";
    }

    // function to call when TextBox LostFocus

    private void textbox_change(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txtbox = e.OriginalSource as TextBox;
        // text from textbox into sting with checking and string format
        txtbox.Text = Globals.numstr2string(txtbox.Text, "0.00");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Email Validation use the following Regex Expression as below in Lost Focus event of the Textbox.

Use **System.Text.RegularExpression** Namespace for Regex.

```
Regex emailExpression = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]{2,28}[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$");
```

and then check it by using below code

```
if (emailExpression.IsMatch(textbox.Text))
{
    //Valid E-mail
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For PhoneNumber Validation use the following code in **PreviewTextInput** event of the Textbox.

```
private void PhoneNumbeTextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = !AreAllValidNumericChars(e.Text);       
}


private bool AreAllValidNumericChars(string str)
{
    bool ret = true;
    if (str == System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CurrencyDecimalSeparator |
            str == System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CurrencyGroupSeparator |
            str == System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NegativeSign |
            str == System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NegativeInfinitySymbol |
            str == System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator |
            str == System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberGroupSeparator |
            str == System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.PercentDecimalSeparator |
            str == System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.PercentGroupSeparator |
            str == System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.PerMilleSymbol |
            str == System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.PositiveInfinitySymbol |
            str == System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.PositiveSign)
            return ret;

    int l = str.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        char ch = str[i];
        ret &= Char.IsDigit(ch);
    }

    return ret;
}
```