# How to remove the country code from the mobile number?

Tags: c#

I want to remove the country code from the mobile number. The method has to satisfy for any country in the world . I have tried to remove the special characters from the mobile number like "+","-" , However i am unable to remove the any country code from the mobile number.
Here is the code for removing special characters in mobile number.

```
 public string RemoveCountryCode()
 {
   string phoneNumber = "441632960960";
   phoneNumber = Regex.Replace(phoneNumber, @"[^\d]", "");
   return phoneNumber ;
}
```

Here the main issue is number of digits in mobile numbers is different from country to country and i research on the topic but many of them wrote static way. here is the link [Best practice for parsing and validating mobile number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563377/best-practice-for-parsing-and-validating-mobile-number)

Comment: You actually should be having country code and mobile number separated to avoid this issue

Comment: different -2 country has different -2 mobile length and they may have same starting char for country code, so you never know from which index mobile started or country code ended. so final you can't do it untill unless you have country code, fixed mobile length

Comment: You can´t do this from your input-string as there are countires with 2 and those with three digits in front (not sure if there even exist contires with more characters). As others already mentioned you should have two input-fields from the beginning to seperate one from another.

Comment: Not everyone is using special symbols in their numbers. Also there are sub-codes that show sub-domains in some countries and are not considered a part of the "main" phone section.
Your task is too broad. Phone numbers probably can't be parsed strictly (because they are not strictly standardized). You may want to ask yourself what exactly you're trying to achieve =)
I've had my share of pain with phone numbers and when I got to 3000+ symbol regexes I've managed to notice that most of our clients come from a few regions so the business task can be simplified.

Comment: Another go is to keep some static data that describes numbers in the regions you're most interested in. You may check for example what patterns does IE notice, it would give you some info on country codes and parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must know the country to achieve this. Please find my answer, it is helpful to you if you have the countries list. And let me know if you have any issues.

```
public string RemoveCountryCode()
    {
        string phonenumber = "+91123123123";

        List<string> countries_list = new List<string>();
        countries_list.Add("+1");
        countries_list.Add("+91");

        foreach(var country in countries_list)
        {
             phonenumber = phonenumber.Replace(country, "");

        }

        return phonenumber;
    }
```

Comment: @prasanthi Welcome

Comment: This will replace the country code also inside the phone number. But it should only removed from  the left.

Answer (score -1):

```
First create a Datatable with all know phone prefix Data like this:
        DM.DTPrefix.Columns.Add("prefix", typeof(System.Int32));
        DM.DTPrefix.Rows.Add(1); //United States
        DM.DTPrefix.Rows.Add(1242); //Bahamas
        DM.DTPrefix.Rows.Add(1246); //Barbados
        DM.DTPrefix.Rows.Add(1264); //Anguilla

        DM.DTPrefix.Rows.Add(20); //Egypt
```

So we have prefix from 1 to 4 chars long (or more?)
Remove + or 00 from your phone number.

lets find if any numbers are in our list of know prefix starting by trying 4 digits, the 3 and so on.
We have to search for the four digits prefix first, then 3 digists, etc.
phone number like 001242 34 56 789
string strSearchPhone = '12423456789' // the phone number without + or 00 and without any other characters.

```
        string strPrefix = "";
        for (int c = 4; c > 0; c--)
        {
            strPrefix = strSearchPhone.Substring(0, c);
            DataRow[] DR = DM.DTPrefix.Select("prefix = " + strPrefix);
            if (DR.Length > 0) // we found the prefix +
            {
                break;
            }

        }
        if (strPrefix != "")
        {
            strSearchPhone = strSearchPhone.Substring(strPrefix.Length);
        }
```

now the remaining string should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score -2):

public string RemoveCountryCode(00966)
{
string phoneNumber = "00966552796159";

return phoneNumber 0552796159

Comment: This isn't even valid code.